# How would I log into gmail.com using rvest R package?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to login to my gmail account using rvest R package.

Here's the code I used

```
url<-"https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin"
g_session   <-html_session(url)
g_form      <-html_form(gession)[[1]]
form_values <-setvalues<-(g_form,"***","***")
submit_form(g_session,form_values)
```

I got the following ouput

> "Error: Could not find possible submission target."

I need help figuring out which part of the above R code is incorrect ?

Comment: you have a few typos: should be `html_form(g_session)` in line 3, and `setvalues(g_form, Email ='***')` on line 4. I then have to submit the form and enter the password: `form_2_values <- {submit_form(g_session,form_values)  %>%
  html_form()}[[1]] %>%
  set_values(Passwd = '***')`

Comment: You may have more luck with the `gmailr` package